# Browser tries to open application/json as a file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a problem with my JSON response in my MVC 3 application. When JSON is responding, my browser cannot handle application/json and tries to open it as a file. However, I'm recieving the correct data in the file.

I've added this to my Global.asax file:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

This is my javascript code:

```
    $('#register).submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            var ai = {
            Firstname: $("#Firstname").val(),
            Lastname: $("#Lastname").val(),
            Email: $("#Email").val()
            };

            var json = $.toJSON(ai);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Person/Create',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: json,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");    
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

And this is my ActionResult method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Personer.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(new { Success = person.ID > 0, Firstname = person.Firstname, Lastname = person.Lastname });
     }
```

I've also added .json (application/json) to the MIME-list in IIE.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access a file with JSON headers in Firefox directly (meaning: you're entering the URL into the address bar), Firefox will download it as a file. However, when you call your JSON in an AJAX request, it'll work the way you want it to.